# httpd.conf on Windows: can't locate API model structure `php8_module`

Tags: php, windows, apache, httpconfiguration

I'm trying to install PHP, Apache and MySQL on Windows, following [these guidelines](https://codebriefly.com/how-to-setup-apache-php-mysql-on-windows-10/). At some point, I am prompted to edit `httpd.conf` to point to my PHP installation. Both the apache directory and the php directory are under `C:\`: `C:\Apache24` and `C:\php-8.0.0beta1-Win32-vs16-x64.`

The relevant lines for my installation are:

```
PHPIniDir "C:/php-8.0.0beta1-Win32-vs16-x64"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .phar
LoadModule php8_module "C:/php-8.0.0beta1-Win32-vs16-x64/php8apache2_4.dll"
```

Unfortunately, these seem to break Apache, since even running `httpd` afterwards yields:

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 542 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `php8_module' in file C:/php-8.0.0beta1-Win32-vs16-x64/php8apache2_4.dll: No error
```

It seems that `php8_module` is not recognized by PowerShell. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your Windows System 32bit or 64 bit?

Comment: And what has PowerShell got to do with any of this?

Comment: That tutorial is a bit old now. Did you install ALL the required MSVC Runtimes specifically the latest ones

Comment: What version of Apache did you install.

Comment: You may find it easier to install something like XAMPP or WAMPServer as then all the heavy lifting is done for you

Comment: Did you download the Thread Safe or NON Thread Safe version of PHP?

Comment: If you are using it for the development purposes:
1) Forget about installing everything one by one
2) Download and install XAMPP.

Comment: @RiggsFolly 64 bit. Powershell is the terminal I have used for all this stuff. Also, I am using apache 2.4. Additionally, thread safe. Based on both of your feedback, xampp or wampserver are the way to go.

Comment: Dont forget to uninstall what you have done so far if you go that way

Answer (score 128):

I had exactly the same problem. I found a solution [here](https://developerf1.com/how-to/install-php-8-on-windows).

As it turned out in PHP 8 we should not use `php8_module` as we would expect, but only plain `php_module`

So the loader line should look like this:

```
LoadModule php_module "c:/Program Files/PHP/php-8.0.0RC2/php8apache2_4.dll"
```

Comment: I ended up downloading an entire stack, fwiw

Comment: Does XAMPP or WAMPServer support PHP 8? On their sites, I can only found 7.4.x versions.

Comment: @Vmxes many thanks by your help, that is 100% efective: **before: LoadModule php7_module** but for PHP8 using **NOW: LoadModule php_module** and that is all, run fine for me :-)

Comment: This worked with Laragon, which many of us prefer to XAMP.

Comment: it worked, I am using Laragon, in file "C:\Laragon\apache2\mod_php.conf " I changed php8_module to php_module and it worked, thanks

Comment: This solution worked beautifully. The tutorials should be updated indeed!

Comment: @Vmxes I am using laragon. When I restart the server, it shows the error again. So I have to go to "C:\Laragon\etc\apache2\mod_php.conf" and change the loader line again.

Comment: @VyR is the real hero for this one. downgraded from PHP 8 to PHP7.4.33

Comment: this helps, there are tutorial and even CHATGPT suggest i add 'php7_module'!!!, it must work, but hmmm who cares at least apache can be started, thx

Answer (score 30):

You would expect that the Apache2 directive for PHP8 would intuitively be:

```
LoadModule php8_module "path/to/PHP/php8apache2_4.dll"
```

But rather you have to use:

```
LoadModule php_module "path/to/PHP/php8apache2_4.dll"
```

I find that strange but that's how it is.

If you now navigate to your Apache2bin directory (something like C:/Apache24/bin)
and check your httpd.conf file for any syntax errors using:

```
httpd -t
```

You should get the output "Syntax OK". Now you can start your apache server without any errors.

Comment: I am using laragon. When I restart the server, it shows the error again. So I have to go to "C:\Laragon\etc\apache2\mod_php.conf" and change the loader line again.

Answer (score 24):

If you are just looking for the answer it is:

```
LoadModule php7_module "C:/Apache/modules/php7apache2_4.dll"
```

If you'd like to read on, I am trying to help people with other issues that come with trying to install php, mysql and apache together.

So normally for the PHP 8 version if you try to install it and try to connect it with MySQL and Apache it will not work which we already know. **IF** you didn't know this, please go and uninstall PHP 8 and install Php 7.4 in your C directory.

Now the line:

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 244 of C:/Apache/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `php_module' in file C:/Apache/modules/php7apache2_4.dll: No error
```

If you notice what the error actually is that of a syntax which is pretty confusing if you go letter by letter trying to fix the issue.
It turns out it is more of a logical error than a syntax error.

Now if you typed this in your config code:

```
LoadModule php_module "C:/Apache/modules/php7apache2_4.dll"
```

You are not wrong or far from the actual solution actually you are 99% correct with this above line.

So if you notice the error line again it states it is unable to locate an API called `php_module`.
So by default for PHP 8 you don't need to change this line as it understands it, but for Php 7.4 you must add a 7 in front of php so it can locate the module.

So the correct line of code to be placed in the config file is:

```
LoadModule php7_module "C:/Apache/modules/php7apache2_4.dll"
```

thank you for patiently reading through this, I hope it helps anyone searching for a more whole answer in relation to trying to download php 7.4, mysql and apache together.

Answer (score 7):

To resolve the error in my case I have to add as

```
LoadModule php_module "c:/php/php8apache2_4.dll"
```

instead of

```
LoadModule php8_module "c:/php/php8apache2_4.dll"
```

My working environment details..

1. Windows 10 64 Bit
2. PHP Version: PHP 8.0.19 64 bit Thread safe version
3. Apache version: httpd-2.4.53-win64-VS16

In httpd.conf file: I have added below line of code on top.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
LoadModule php_module "c:/php/php8apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "c:/php"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
LoadModule php[PHP_MAIN_VERSION]_module "path/to/PHP/php[PHP_MAIN_VERSION]apache2_4.dll"
```

Example:

```
LoadModule php7_module "C:/php7.4.27/php7apache2_4.dll"
```

Comment: Well done - annoying little bugger.

Answer (score 2):

It should look like below:

```
# PHP8 module
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
LoadModule php_module "c:/php/php8apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "c:/php"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but in my case it worked changing this line in the httpd.conf file from

```
#ServerName www.example.com:80
```

to

```
ServerName localhost
```

And it worked

Not forgetting @vmxes answer

Answer (score 0):

from https://windows.php.net/download#php-8.0
you have to download the "Thread Safe" version. otherwise you have no "php8apache2_4.dll" and you need that so that php8 works with apache in XAMPP.
just download this version and you have

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here, so I went to http.conf and changed the line: LoadModule php8_module "c:\PHP8\php8apache2_4.dll" to LoadModule php_module "c:\PHP8\php8apache2_4.dll"

Just remove the 8 and it works. At least for me it worked here.
Hope this helps.